# Message: stale element reference: stale element not found

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have developed a script for scraping data from twitter, the problem is i am getting this error message in the debugging log and the script crashes after this, it happens in random times. Can you some tell me what is the issue and how can  I make the script not crash and bypass this error message
Below is the code and also the error image i have attached

```
import csv
import datetime
import os
import random
import re
import time
import urllib
from collections import defaultdict

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

userInput = input("Enter tag name: ")

url = 'https://twitter.com/'
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
# Get the user's home directory
home_dir = os.path.expanduser("~")
# Construct the Selenium profile directory path
selenium_profile_path = os.path.join(home_dir, "AppData", "Local", "Google", "Chrome", "SeleniumProfile")
# If the Selenium profile directory doesn't exist, create it
if not os.path.exists(selenium_profile_path):
    os.makedirs(selenium_profile_path)


# Function to create Chrome options with specified arguments
def create_chrome_options(headless=False):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={selenium_profile_path}")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')  # 3 disables logging
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

    if headless:
        pass
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

    return chrome_options


driver = None
data = []
encountered_ids = set()


# Run the driver in headless mode and check if it gets redirected to the home page
def run_headless():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=create_chrome_options(headless=True))
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)  # Adjust this sleep time as needed
    if "https://twitter.com/home" in driver.current_url:
        perform_tasks()
        return True
    else:
        driver.quit()
        return False


# Run the driver without headless mode and wait until it gets redirected to the home page
def run_non_headless():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=create_chrome_options(headless=False))
    driver.get(url)
    while "https://twitter.com/home" not in driver.current_url:
        time.sleep(2)  # Adjust this sleep time as needed
    driver.quit()
    return True


scroll_count = 0


def scroll_down():
    global driver, scroll_count
    # Get the current scroll position
    current_scroll_position = driver.execute_script("return window.scrollY;")

    # Calculate the new scroll position by adding the scroll distance to the current position
    new_scroll_position = current_scroll_position + 0.01
    # Scroll down using JavaScript to the new scroll position
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {new_scroll_position});")
    time.sleep(random.randint(7, ))


def aggregate_and_save_to_csv():
    global data
    user_data = defaultdict(lambda: {'total_posts': 0, 'post_retweet': 0, 'post_favorite': 0})

    # Aggregate data for each post_user
    for post in data:
        user = post['post_user']
        retweets = int(post['post_retweet'].replace(',', ''))
        favorites = int(post['post_favorite'].replace(',', ''))

        user_data[user]['total_posts'] += 1
        user_data[user]['post_retweet'] += retweets
        user_data[user]['post_favorite'] += favorites

    # Save aggregated data to a CSV file
    # Save aggregated data to a CSV file
    with open(f'{userInput}_{current_time}.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['post_user', 'total_posts', 'total_post_retweet', 'total_post_favorite', 'trend']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for user, stats in user_data.items():
            writer.writerow({'post_user': user, 'total_posts': stats['total_posts'],
                             'total_post_retweet': stats['post_retweet'],
                             'total_post_favorite': stats['post_favorite'], 'trend': userInput})


def scrap_post():
    global driver, data, encountered_ids
    post_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                     ".css-1dbjc4n.r-1loqt21.r-18u37iz.r-1ny4l3l.r-1udh08x.r-1qhn6m8.r-i023vh.r-o7ynqc.r-6416eg")
    for post in post_list:

        try:
            match = re.search(r"/(\d+)$", post.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                            ".css-4rbku5.css-18t94o4.css-901oao.r-1loqt21.r-xoduu5.r-1q142lx.r-1w6e6rj.r-a023e6.r-16dba41.r-9aw3ui.r-rjixqe.r-bcqeeo.r-3s2u2q.r-qvutc0").get_attribute(
                'href'))
            if match:
                post_id = match.group(1)
                if post_id in encountered_ids:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
        post.location_once_scrolled_into_view

        post_user = post.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-901oao.css-16my406.r-poiln3.r-bcqeeo.r-qvutc0")
        filtered_elements = [element for element in post_user if element.text.startswith("@")]
        post_user = filtered_elements[0].text
        numbers = post.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".css-1dbjc4n.r-xoduu5.r-1udh08x")
        try:
            post_retweet = numbers[1].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                   ".css-901oao.css-16my406.r-poiln3.r-bcqeeo.r-qvutc0").text
        except (NoSuchElementException, IndexError):
            post_retweet = str(0)
        try:
            post_favorite = numbers[2].find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                                    ".css-901oao.css-16my406.r-poiln3.r-bcqeeo.r-qvutc0").text
        except (NoSuchElementException, IndexError):
            post_favorite = str(0)
        encountered_ids.add(post_id)
        post_dict = {
            "id": post_id,
            "post_user": post_user,
            "post_retweet": post_retweet,
            "post_favorite": post_favorite,
        }
        data.append(post_dict)
    if post_list:
        post_list[-1].location_once_scrolled_into_view


def getLatestWithoutHash():
    global driver, data
    # driver.get(f'https://twitter.com/hashtag/{userInput}')
    driver.get(f'https://twitter.com/search?q={userInput}&src=trend_click&vertical=trends')
    num_times_to_scroll = 10  # Number of times to scroll
    new_page_length = 0
    num_times_scrolled = 0
    while True:
        scrap_post()
        aggregate_and_save_to_csv()
        scroll_down()
        num_times_scrolled = num_times_scrolled + 1
        old_page_length = new_page_length
        new_page_length = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
        if old_page_length == new_page_length:
            if num_times_scrolled == num_times_to_scroll:
                break
        else:
            num_times_scrolled = 0


def getLatestWithHash():
    global driver, data
    # driver.get(f'https://twitter.com/hashtag/{userInput}')
    driver.get(f'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23{userInput}&src=trend_click&vertical=trends')
    num_times_to_scroll = 10  # Number of times to scroll
    new_page_length = 0
    num_times_scrolled = 0
    while True:
        scrap_post()
        aggregate_and_save_to_csv()
        scroll_down()
        num_times_scrolled = num_times_scrolled + 1
        old_page_length = new_page_length
        new_page_length = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
        if old_page_length == new_page_length:
            if num_times_scrolled == num_times_to_scroll:
                break
        else:
            num_times_scrolled = 0




# Run the tasks after getting to the home page
def perform_tasks():
    print("Data scraping started...")
    global driver, data
    while True:
        getLatestWithHash()

    # Headless mode run


if run_headless():
    pass
elif run_non_headless():
    run_headless()

# Close the browser window when you're done
if driver:
    driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: the DOM is probably updating after scroll... when scrap_post is called the DOM is in the process of updating causing stale element.  Short way to fix is to change your random sleep: time.sleep(random.randint(7, )) to something fixed and large enough account for the DOM updating (and probably move that to scrap_post method).  Long way to fix, is to catch stale element exceptions and re-get your webelement reference array if caught.